# gradient for vector or matrix valued functioms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

[here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~zkolter/course/15-884/linalg-review.pdf) (pageg 21) it says : It is very important to remember that the gradient of a function is only defined if the function is real-valued, that is, if it returns a scalar value. We can not, for example, take the gradient
of Ax, A ∈ Rn×n with respect to x, since this quantity is vector-valued.

while [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf) (section # : gradient of linear functions) and [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/mc.pdf) (D.1.2 Product rules for matrix-functions) and many other places i have observed identities and formulae of taking gradient of vector and matrix valued functions. In fact in the second link[3](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/mc.pdf) they talk about gradient for product of matrices.

Can some one help with clearing up on the contradiction ? What is the correct way to understand gradient for matrices.